# Texture paint on top of existing texture

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I’m constantly running into problems with texture painting-related things. Just don’t seem to get a complete grip of it.

I have two walls; one with a brick image texture on, and the other is a simple noise textured. I now want to paint scratches, dirt and graffiti on the walls.

How would you best suggest I do this so I can paint on the walls? A new image texture doesn’t have transparent background so that option looks crap.

Comment: hello, there are several ways to do it, you can use your scratches as a mask, or put it over the brick wall if it has a transparent background, or use a MixRGB to put it over, etc... but maybe show your images?

Comment: Hi. I want to paint the scratches/graffiti/dirt... not use a PNG or any image. If I use a MixRGB the background color of my texture painted scratch-/graffiti-image is still there...

Comment: Yes, but have you inserted alpha channel in the mix factor of MixRGB?

Comment: Screenshots will help here, and I cannot understand why you are talking about texture painting if you are not wanting to use an image to paint on.